# Set ImageView to current image of UIButton on tap in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

In building an app I'm trying do as it says in the title, I want to change an Imageview to the image currently set in a UIButton by tapping that button.

I know how to do this:

```
@IBAction func play1(_ sender: AnyObject){
    Activepic1.image = UIImage(named: "Blank Image")
}
```

Right now it sets the Activepic1 to a "Blank Image" that I have in my asset library. I did that to test the app as is.. but what I want to happen is for it to assign whatever image is currently displayed as the UIButton.

Is there a function I can use to put the Current Image of the button rather than using the (named: "asset") function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to create an outlet (and hook it up) for your button as well as your action and just access the button's image from it.

**Using swift 3**

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageBttn: UIButton!
....

@IBAction func play1(_ sender: Any){
    Activepic1.image = imageBttn.currentImage!
}
```

**Alternative way without having to create a new outlet**

```
@IBAction func play1(_ sender: Any){
    Activepic1.image = sender.currentImage!
}
```

The first solution can utilise any button hooked up to the `imageBttn` outlet while the second strictly uses the button that is connected to the action itself.

Comment: That was a very quick response and it worked! Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: No problem~ Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code which worked for me I used storyBoard

1) Connect the `UIButton` and `ImageView` to the `ViewController.swift` file

```
  @IBOutlet var myImageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton!
```

2) Define the action of the Action of the UIButton as:

```
@IBAction func myButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
 myImageView.image = myButton.imageView!.image 
}
```

**Before tapping Button**

[image]

**After tapping Button**

[image]